# How to combine 2 webElements from a page factory setup in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I am using Page Factory set up for my project where in I have the following:

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[contains(@text,'Monthly Pass')]")
private WebElement monthlyPass;

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[contains(@text,'Ten Ride Ticket')]")
     private WebElement tenRideTicket;

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using=""./parent::android.view.View/following-sibling::android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]")
private WebElement AmountForThePass;

public void getAmountValue(){

  if(monthlyPass.isDisplayed){

      // Here I want to findElement 'AmountForThePass' from the element 'monthlyPass'
     // The actual element is //*[contains(@text,'Monthly Pass')]/parent::android.view.View/following- 
     //                          sibling::android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]
     //   which I have broken into 2 parts.The second part 'AmountForThePass' is same for other  
     // 'tenRideTicket'
  }
}
```

How can I combine the WebElements (monthlyPass with AmountForThePass) OR (tenRideTicket with AmountForThePass)

Comment: What's wrong with `//*[contains(@text,'Monthly Pass')]/parent::android.view.View/following-sibling::android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]`?

Comment: Do you want to use `tenRideTicket` and `AmountForThePass` as independent page objects or you only use them with combination with `monthlyPass`?

Comment: I want to use tenRideTicket and AmountForThePass for one instance and monthlyPass and AmountForThePass for second instance.